# How to show the prototyping preview in Playgrounds?

Tags: ios, swift3, swift-playground

I can't find an updated article that shows how to show a live preview of my UIView animations. Methods like XCShowView() aren't used in Swift anymore, according to the error I received in the playground editor.

Does anyone know how to show the prototyping preview in Playgrounds?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Xcode 8:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)))
v.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = v
```

Create a playground with that code and you should see a green box on the live view.

Remember to show the "live" assistant editor. See [PlaygroundSupport reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/playgroundsupport) for more.